# 「fatal: unable to write new index file」というエラーを解決したいです。

Tags: linux

rails-tutorialをしているプログラミング初学者です。
AWSの環境でチュートリアルを進めていたのですが、ターミナルに「fatal: unable to write new index file」というエラーが表示されました。
このエラーを解決したいというのが質問です。

#### 問題点

このエラーの意味するところは「ファイルの空き容量が足りない」ということを指すみたいです。なので「容量を増やすか、不要なファイルを削除する」というのが解決策になるみたいなので、後者の不要なファイルを削除する方向で考えています。
しかし、その「不要なファイル」というのはどのような観点で見れば見つけられるのかがわからないです。（疑問点１）

そこで容量を一番食っているファイルを調べてみました。すると `/dev/xvda1` というファイルで9.7G使用されているということなので、このファイルが怪しいと感じています。

[image: 参考に画像を添付しました。]

しかし、そのファイルをopenしてみても「no files found」と表示されます。（疑問点２）

少し派生的に疑問がそれるのですが、そもそもRailsチュートリアルしか進めていないような状態でファイルの容量はいっぱいになるのでしょうか。（疑問点３）

このエラーの解決に向けてLinuxについても検索はしてみましたが、疑問の解決には自分の力不足により至らなかったので、質問させていただきました。

このエラーの解決に向けて何かアドバイスをいただけると幸いです。
他に質問をする上で不足している情報などがありましたら、教えていただきましたらすぐに提示致します。

Comment: 緊急 : `/dev` 以下はその正体を理解しないまま触らないでください。 `/dev` 以下は実のところファイルではありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df` は「ファイルシステムの使用量を確認する」コマンドで、表示された結果の一番左の列はファイルシステムの種類や場所を表します。
`/dev/xvda1` はざっくり言うとディスクを表す特殊なファイルなので、エディタ等で開くことはできません。

ここで見るべきなのは一番右の列 "Mounted on" の部分ですが、「"/" ルートディレクトリが 100%」までしか分からないので、別のコマンドで調べていきます。

私が良く使うのは、`du` コマンドでディレクトリごとの使用状況を少しずつ絞り込んでいく方法です。
デフォルトでは指定したディレクトリ以下のサブディレクトリをすべて辿って表示するので、少々見づらいため、`--max-depth N` オプションで辿る階層を制限します。

**実行例:**

```
$  du -h --max-depth 1 /
0       /proc
0       /misc
276M    /home
50M     /etc
5.9G    /usr
193M    /boot
0       /sys
56M     /opt
16K     /lost+found
7.6G    /var
0       /dev
2.4M    /tmp
570M    /root
4.0K    /srv
0       /net
4.0K    /media
1.2M    /run
0       /mnt
15G     /
```

実行結果を見て、容量を食っていそうなディレクトリを改めて `du` で調べていきます。

```
$ du -h --max-depth 1 /var
12K     /var/kerberos
2.8G    /var/lib
4.0K    /var/yp
4.0K    /var/local
9.0M    /var/www
4.0K    /var/nis
4.0K    /var/opt
157M    /var/crash
4.0K    /var/account
4.2G    /var/log
8.0K    /var/empty
20K     /var/db
4.0K    /var/adm
4.0K    /var/preserve
231M    /var/tmp
177M    /var/spool
202M    /var/cache
4.0K    /var/gopher
4.0K    /var/games
7.6G    /var
```

もし削除する場合にも、システムで必要なファイルを誤って削除しないよう注意してください。
あくまで自分が作業をして作成したと思われる (心当たりのある) ファイルに限って削除を実施しましょう。